# How to check if an accordion is being clicked so that I can pass a value to ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to check if the accordion is being triggered or clicked. I have multiple accordions. If I'm going to click one, how can I determine if that accordion is being clicked?

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
        href="#collapseOne"></a>
    </h4>
</div>
 <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
        href="#collapseTwo"></a>
    </h4>
  </div>



<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
    // Value inserted here after passing to ajax
    </div>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
    // Value inserted here after passing to ajax
    </div>
</div>


$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "getAccordion.php", // something I want to query
    data: {type:type},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data) 
    {
        //pass values to body of accordion
    }
}
```

Comment: That only is HTML markup... Where's your code?

Comment: I edited my code

Comment: So you want to call the Ajax function when you click an accordion open? If so, Is that the SAME Ajax request that you want to make? Any data to pass on?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I can pass an id as indicator, I have 10 accordions they are all sql queries but it made my site lagged. I need to minimized it by querying one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```js
$('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('href')); // Here you will get the targeted ID
  var targetID = $(this).attr('href');
  
  /*$.ajax({
   url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {id:targetID}
    ...
  });*/
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">test</a>
    </h4>
</div>

<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
    // Value inserted here after passing to ajax
    </div>
</div>
```

I've commented out the `AJAX` call, you need to enable that based on you requirement.

I've attached an `click event` with `anchor` tag.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but still it didnt work :(

Comment: @KilluaKunnichi What error you are getting in your browser console?

Comment: @KilluaKunnichi Can you explain what you are looking for, definitely will help you out. I'm bit confuse with your question

Comment: Thank you @Shiladitya. This is the situation, I have 10 accordions they are all sql queries but it made my site lagged. I need to minimized it by querying one at a time. So I decided, when I clicked each accordion, thats the time it will query, rather than querying them all. Im having a problem identifying thats the accordion I clicked.

Comment: @KilluaKunnichi Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/q23ca63d/1/ . Here I've used you latest `HTML` code. So, what I understood you want to send some id from the clicked accordion to get the data & append it to the accordion panel. Right?

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 2):

You wish to load some extra content "delayed" from initial page load.

You will not want it to load every time a tab is clicked!
So an array to store which tabs have been opened will be useful.

Then, the script will proceed with an Ajax request only if the tab `id` (stored in the anchor's `href`) is not in that array.

An additional `data` attribute would be useful in your markup, so from a `click`, you'd be able to pass it to make the right request to your database.
See `data-id` in your the HTML markup.

```js
console.clear();

// An array to store loaded tabs.
var tabsLoaded = [];

// Tab click handler
$("[data-toggle]").on("click", function(){
  
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  //console.log( href );
  
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  //console.log( id );

  // Proceed to Ajax request only if that tab hasn't already been loaded.
  if( tabsLoaded.indexOf(href) == -1){
    
    // Store that tab id in array to prevent useless requests
    tabsLoaded.push(href);
    
    console.log("Here we go Ajax!")
    /*    // Ajax can't work in this snippet... But that is the code I suggest.
    // Ajax!
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "getAccordion.php",
      data: {id:id},            // Pass the id got from the data-id
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        //pass values to body of accordion
        $(href).html(data.someProperty);
      }
    });
    */
    
    // Simulating an Ajax response
    $(href).html("Hello! I'm Ajax response from query of id "+id+".");
  }else{
    // That else only is usefull for that demo... You can remove it.
    console.log("No need for Ajax, the content is already loaded.")
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" data-id="1">Tab 1</a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" data-id="2">Tab 2</a>
  </h4>
</div>

<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <!-- Value inserted here after passing to ajax -->
  </div>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <!-- Value inserted here after passing to ajax -->
  </div>
</div>
```